# KD-Tree "median of list" construction

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

I've coded up a KD-Tree in Java using the ["median of list"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Construction) algorithm for constructing a more balanced tree. It seems to work fine when using the data provided by the wiki, note that the wikipedia example uses only X,Y values, so it doesn't evaluate the Z depth.

From wikipedia:

```
point_list = [(2,3), (5,4), (9,6), (4,7), (8,1), (7,2)]
```

[image]

From [my java program](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/KdTree.java):

```
depth=0 id=(7.0, 2.0, 0.0)
├── [left] depth=1 id=(5.0, 4.0, 0.0)
│   ├── [left] depth=2 id=(2.0, 3.0, 0.0)
│   └── [right] depth=2 id=(4.0, 7.0, 0.0)
└── [right] depth=1 id=(9.0, 6.0, 0.0)
    └── [left] depth=2 id=(8.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

But when I use the "median of list" approach on this data, it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
point list = [(1,0,-1), (1,0,-2), (1,0,1), (1,0,2)]
```

I get a tree like this:

```
depth=0 id=(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
├── [left] depth=1 id=(1.0, 0.0, -2.0)
│   └── [left] depth=2 id=(1.0, 0.0, -1.0)
└── [right] depth=1 id=(1.0, 0.0, 2.0)
```

Which doesn't look correct because (1.0, 0.0, 2.0) is to the right of (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) but they are essentially equal because their Y values are equal. Also, (1.0, 0.0, -1.0) is to the left of (1.0, 0.0, -2.0) and it should be to the right since it's Z value is greater.

I think the problem stems from having equal X and Y values and only variable Z values, so the median of the list doesn't really split the list accurately.

... original code following the wiki's python code ...

```
private static KdNode createNode(List<XYZPoint> list, int k, int depth) {
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return null;

    int axis = depth % k;
    if (axis == X_AXIS) Collections.sort(list, X_COMPARATOR);
    else if (axis == Y_AXIS) Collections.sort(list, Y_COMPARATOR);
    else Collections.sort(list, Z_COMPARATOR);

    KdNode node = null;
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        int mediaIndex = list.size() / 2;
        node = new KdNode(k, depth, list.get(mediaIndex));
        if ((mediaIndex - 1) >= 0) {
            List<XYZPoint> less = list.subList(0, mediaIndex);
            if (less.size() > 0) {
                node.lesser = createNode(less, k, depth + 1);
                node.lesser.parent = node;
            }
        }
        if ((mediaIndex + 1) <= (list.size() - 1)) {
            List<XYZPoint> more = list.subList(mediaIndex + 1, list.size());
            if (more.size() > 0) {
                node.greater = createNode(more, k, depth + 1);
                node.greater.parent = node;
            }
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

... new code based on my comment ...

```
private static KdNode createNode(List<XYZPoint> list, int k, int depth) {
    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return null;

    int axis = depth % k;
    if (axis == X_AXIS) Collections.sort(list, X_COMPARATOR);
    else if (axis == Y_AXIS) Collections.sort(list, Y_COMPARATOR);
    else Collections.sort(list, Z_COMPARATOR);

    KdNode node = null;
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        int medianIndex = list.size() / 2;
        node = new KdNode(k, depth, list.get(medianIndex));
        List<XYZPoint> less = new ArrayList<XYZPoint>(list.size()-1);
        List<XYZPoint> more = new ArrayList<XYZPoint>(list.size()-1);
        //Process list to see where each non-median point lies
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            if (i==medianIndex) continue;
            XYZPoint p = list.get(i);
            if (KdNode.compareTo(depth, k, p, node.id)<=0) {
                less.add(p);
            } else {
                more.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (less.size() > 0) {
            node.lesser = createNode(less, k, depth + 1);
            node.lesser.parent = node;
        }
        if (more.size() > 0) {
            node.greater = createNode(more, k, depth + 1);
            node.greater.parent = node;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's seem like after I choose the median, I'll have to process the list to see where each point lies in relation to the median. Won't this make creating the KD-Tree a n*((n log n) + (n)) process? (n log n) to sort the list and (n) to see where each element lies in relation to the median.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem indeed has to do with equal coordinates and arises from how you split the nodes into `less` and `more` parts. Since you have the median index, why not use the index for splitting instead of checking the coordinates? Just change the condition in `createNode` on line 116 from

```
if (KdNode.compareTo(depth, k, p, node.id)<=0) {
```

to

```
if (i<medianIndex) {
```

Btw: there are more efficient algorithms to partition a list into lower, median, upper than sorting. (lower and upper parts do not need to be sorted! see e.g. the implementation of `std::nth_element` in the C++ stdlib - sorry, I'm that much into Java programming)

Comment: The approach you suggest is the way my code originally looked. Say the data is (1,0,-2), (1,0,-1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,0,2), if I sort it according to the X (first) value and look for the median, I'll get the   (1,0,0) point. You cannot assume the points with greater indices [(1,0,1), (1,0,2)] are truly to the right of the median. The problem arises when all points have the same value for the same axis.

Comment: Also, thanks for the nth_element suggestion. Seems like Java is missing a 'Quick Select' type algorithm but maybe I'll roll my own.

Comment: What's wrong with putting points with equal coordinates also on the `more` side? You just need to adjust your search methods accordingly. I have a very efficient kd-tree implementation in C++ that's perfectly balanced, i.e. `less.size()-more.size() == 0 or 1` always holds. This obviously can only be achieved if you allow to have points with equal coordinates in both sides (`less` and `more`); otherwise you are asking for too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the essential question at this point is: what, exactly, do you want to do with the KD-tree?

- If you just want to find a closest point using X- and Y-distance only, then the algorithm you have is perfectly fine - you'll find at least one of the four points at equal XY-distance from your example.
- If you want to find *all* closest points in XY-distance, then still keep the KD-tree building function the same, but just change all '<' operators in your lookup function to '<='. If you find a KD-tree point exactly at the query point, you'll still need to descend down an arbitrary child of that tree until you find a leaf. Then go up the tree as usual in a KD-tree, always descending down the sibling tree if it could potentially match the shortest distance you have found so far.
- If you want to use distance involving X-, Y-, and Z-coordinates, you need to make your tree a 3-dimensional KD-tree, with X-, Y-, and Z-layers alternating (or potentially with some clever scheme for choosing which dimension to subdivide next).